Calculate cone direction and angle known quadric function
Now I have the quadric function of a cone:
$$\mathbf{x^T} A \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b^T} \mathbf{x} + c = 0$$
The function is:
$$U^T \left( \frac{X - V}{|X - V|} \right) = \cos(\theta)$$
both sides squared:
$${(\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{V})^T}(\cos^2(\theta)\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U^T})\left({\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{V}}\right) = 0$$
$$Q=\cos^2(\theta)\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{U}\mathbf{U^T}$$
I can calculate vertex V:
$$ \mathbf{V} = -\frac{1}{2}b^TQ^{-1}$$
but I don't know how to calculate direction $\mathbf{U}$ and angle $\theta$
